# Some Video formats not working on mediaPlayer

Tags: android, video, media-player, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I used mediaPlayer and surfaceView to read videos like this :

```
   mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
   mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

   mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, uriVideo);
   mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

   @Override
   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int  height) {

   }

   @Override
   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
      mMediaPlayer.start();
   }
```

the problem, there is some type of videos (.avi, .mkv, ...) not working on this player, the same videos work on other video player like VLC player; and I get this error

```
java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
   at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1113)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1070)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1009)
   at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:956)    
   at com.geniussecurity.pleo.VideoActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoActivity.java:385)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:583)
   at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
   at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1880)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)   
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5426)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Supported Media Formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) before using `MediaPlayer`.

VLC and other players uses their own native layers for decoding and playing video.

You can try to use some of video playback libs based on ffmpeg:

1. [jkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer)
2. [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg)